# How can I avoid a redirection to the home page when I logout on django?

Tags: html, django

I'm working on a website for an internship. I've implemented a logout button but when I logout, after the user deconnection, I have a redirection on the home page, but I don't want this, for example if I'm in  `url.com/toto/tata`, after the logout I would like to stay in this path and not have a rediction to `url.com/home`.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url "account_logout" %}" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}                                     
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">Logout</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you handling the logout logic in a custom view or are you using django's default logout view?

Comment: I'm using the default logout view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `next` input to your logout form as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
```